# Possible for Xcode Re-Indent to keep leading spaces in Swift "markdown" comments?

Tags: xcode, swift2

Consider the following simple code block example in a Swift 2 comment:

`````
/**
````
if a < 0 {  
    a = doSomething(a)  // <- 4 space indentation
}  
````  
*/
`````

In Xcode 7, Editor > Strucuture > Re-Indent removes the leading spaces:

`````
/**
````
if a < 0 {  
a = doSomething(a)  // <-- indent is removed  
}  
````  
*/
`````

Is there a way to keep the spaces from being removed by Xcode 7 Re-Indent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Unicode `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE` characters are not removed by Xcode Re-Indent.

A `U+0A00` character can be inserted via the OS X system Character Viewer. The `NO-BREAK SPACE` can be added to the Character Viewer favorites for convenience.

So, this is a work-around (since Xcode Re-Indent does not appear to have an option to honor spaces with-in comments) for projects where UTF-8 source files are used.